# Practical usage of AutoMapper with POST request

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, automapper, dto

In a `GET` request, I can create a mapping from my back-end model to a customized DTO with `AutoMapper` with ease. However, I have some concerns when using `AutoMapper` with `POST` requests.

Suppose a user orders a product online, he sends the server a `POST` request with some required data. The fact is, not every piece of data in the back-end model is sent by the user. Let's say the `ID` of the `Order` is a `GUID` which is generated automatically when the entry is inserted into the database; or maybe there are other properties which are auto-incremented. All of these *cannot-be-mapped* properties lead to a lot of `.ForMember(dest => dest.myProperty, opt => opt.Ignore())` chains, and extra handling on the mapped instance after `var mappedInstance = Mapper.Map<PostDTO, BackEndModel>(postDTO)`.

Is `AutoMapper` not designed for the aforementioned scenario? What is the practice for handling the model-mapping process if the back-end model is much more complex than the DTO?

---

### Update

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ICollection<PossibleChoice> PossibleChoices { get; set; }
}

public class PossibleChoice
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("MultipleChoiceQuestion")]
    public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ChoiceIndex { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    public MultipleChoiceQuestion MultipleChoiceQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

The user sends a request to create a new question. Only 2 fields are sent.

```
{
    "Question": "How are you?",
    "Answers": [
        { "Text": "I am fine." },
        { "Text": "Feeling bad." }
    ]
}
```

Properties that are missing at this stage:

- MultipleChoiceQuestionId

  - Generated after the insertion
- ChoiceIndex

  - Auto-incremented from 1 up to the number of answers available

Without manual mapping, how to handle this situation with `AutoMapper`?

Comment: When I run into a similar scenario, I interpret my own hesitation to use automatic mapping as a strong indicator that there is too much business logic involved, and hence resort to manual mapping instead. The fact that you turn to SO is maybe indicator enough :)

Comment: Is it common in the field to use mapper plugins for handling `insert` requests?

Comment: I typically only use AutoMapper to flatten to DTOs or view model. AutoMapper is great for flattening but not so good for reproducing a _valid_ object tree that will persisted back to the database.

Comment: Jasen, that's exactly what I am wondering because many articles on the web state that it is absolutely viable and feasible for `AutoMapper` to handle the mapping in both directions, `DTO <---> back-end model`. However, I find myself to be in the situation mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Define your DTOs to be something like this:

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestionDto
{
    // This property could stay here, because you may need to use the same DTO for update (PUT), 
    // which means you need the Id to distinguish and validate the DTO data against the URL id
    //public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId { get; set; } 

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PossibleChoiceDto> PossibleChoices { get; set; }
}

public class PossibleChoiceDto
{
    // This can go from this dto, because this DTO is a child dto for its parent.
    //public Guid MultipleChoiceQuestionId { get; set; }

    // This property could stay here, because you may need to use the same DTO for update (PUT), 
    // which means you need the Id to know which Choice was updated.
    //public int ChoiceIndex { get; set; }

    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

2- You create a mapping between the entity and the corresponding Dto like this,  make sure you call this code from the global.asax file.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MultipleChoiceQuestion, MultipleChoiceQuestionDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<MultipleChoiceQuestionDto, MultipleChoiceQuestion>()
    .ForMember(m => m.MultipleChoiceQuestionId, e => e.Ignore()); // you force automapper to ignore this property

Mapper.CreateMap<PossibleChoice, PossibleChoiceDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PossibleChoiceDto, PossibleChoice>()
    .ForMember(m => m.MultipleChoiceQuestion, e => e.Ignore()) //
    .ForMember(m => m.MultipleChoiceQuestionId, e => e.Ignore())
    .ForMember(m => m.ChoiceIndex, e => e.Ignore());
```

3- In your controller.Post you need to map from the DTO to the entity and save the mapped entity to the database.

Now, the above solution will work for you for POST, however, you need to think about the PUT scenario and soon you will realize that you need the Ids to be included in the DTOs, and if you decided to do that then you need to revisit the mapping in point 2 and remove the Ignore code for the properties that you decided to include in the DTO.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But if I remove the `Ignore` code from `MultipleChoiceQuestion`, no `Guid` is present at the stage of `POST` (creating a new question). What can I do to cater for both request actions?

Comment: Then you will map the Guid's default value,  but in the case of the put it will be the actual Guid value which allows you to map the question or the answer to the original one in the database.

Comment: How to set a default `Guid` when creating a new question? The `Guid` is `DatabaseGenerated`. When I call `SaveChanges()`, there will be runtime error indicating the `PRIMARY KEY constraint` is violated, if the default value you are mentioning is always of the same value.

Comment: Every type in .net has a default value, maybe null like with object type, or 0 like with integer, so the same will be with Guid, so when EF finds the default value for Guid assigned to the id and the entity state was added it will generate the Guid's id before saving the entity to the database.

Comment: What I mean by the default value is the value that will assigned to your property when you define a Guid variable without assigning any value. You can debug that and see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where in your architecture you're using AutoMapper, but you could conceptually whitelist the properties before doing the automapping.  For example, if you're in MVC and you're doing modelbinding, there are techniques (e.g. in the UpdateModel method) to include or exclude a list of properties.

Comment: Currently I am trying to use `AutoMapper` in a `POST` endpoint for inserting new entries. I find it lots of properties in my model cannot be mapped as there is no data to map from. The result is I have to write lines and lines of `Ignore()` statements and post-process the object after undergoing the mapping process.

Comment: No, I got that from your question. I meant, where are you doing AutoMapping? Is it in an MVC app or some other web app framework?  If in MVC, is it in a custom ModelBinder, or in some other part of the application?

Comment: I am using Web API 2.

Comment: You should be able to just use a custom model for the posted values that doesn't include th things you don't want to map, then, no?

Comment: So, just go for manual mapping from custom model to back-end model?